# Haskell Sqlite3 challenge

Tags: haskell, sqlite

In Real World Haskell this is an example of the dbase module HDBC:

```
run conn "INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)" [toSql 0, toSql "zero"]
```

Question is: VALUES (?,?) seem bad practice to me, but if I name the columns:

```
run conn "INSERT INTO test VALUES (id, desc)" [toSql 0, toSql "zero"]
```

I get an error:

```
*** Exception: SqlError {seState = "", seNativeError = 1, seErrorMsg = "prepare 34: INSERT INTO test VALUES (id,desc): no such column: id"}
```

Strange, since the columns are actually named 'id' and 'desc'. Apostrophs maybe?

```
run conn "INSERT INTO test VALUES ('id', 'desc')" [toSql 0, toSql "zero"]
```

But results in following:

```
*** Exception: SqlError {seState = "", seNativeError = -1, seErrorMsg = "In HDBC execute, received [SqlInt64 3,SqlString \"Newco\"] but expected 0 args."}
```

But I really hate having to put 20 question marks. Can you please help me out?

Comment: From the documentation, you need to use `:id` and `:desc` to name your parameters in the string: `r <- queryNamed c "SELECT id,text FROM posts WHERE id = :id AND date >= :date" [":id" := postId, ":date" := afterDate]`

Comment: If you want to specify which columns to bind the values to, `"INSERT INTO test(id,desc) VALUES (?,?)"`.

Comment: Use https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent for sqlite interaction.

Comment: @Shawn: that addresses naming the columns, thanks for that, but do I still need to add '?' for representing each VALUE in column? The example below has only 2 columns, but what if I have 10? Will it look like (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)? Seems very awkward to me.

`run conn "INSERT INTO test (id,desc) VALUES (?,?)"
                             [ toSql (3 :: Int)
                             , toSql ("Newco" :: String)
                             ]`

Comment: Per the documentation, `run conn "INSERT INTO test (id,desc) VALUES (:id,:desc)" [":id" := toSql (3 :: Int), ":desc" := toSql ("Newco" :: String) ]`